# Where can I buy the sefer Meor Einayim by Rabbi Azaria min Haadumim (dei Rossi)?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

[Rabbi Azariah dei Rossi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azariah_dei_Rossi) wrote a sefer called Meor Einayim. It was/is a [controversial](https://kotzkblog.blogspot.com/2018/02/162-how-meor-einayim-was-almost-burned.html) book which the [Maharal famously argued against](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/meor-einayim-the-maharal) in his book Be'er Hagola. There is an English translation of Meor Eiynayim available [here](https://yalebooks.yale.edu/book/9780300079067/light-eyes). I want to know if the full Hebrew version is available somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several editions of Meor Einayim available on [Hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx)

If you open them you will be presented with an option to order a print version from an external site.

For example, [here is a link](http://www.publishyoursefer.com/reprints/t/7306) to the buying page for one of the editions.

Note that not all the editions have an available reprint for sale. The one linked above, obviously, does.